# Canonical way for empty Array in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the canonical way to get an empty array in Scala? `new Array[String](0)` is too verbose.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
Array[String]()
```

You can leave out the `[String]` part if it can be inferred (e.g. `methodThatAlwaysTakesAStringArray( Array() )`).

Comment: This version seems to create an empty sequence and call `Array.apply()` on that sequence. So it's not exactly the same as `new Array[String](0)`.

Comment: Could you explain why this is preferable over 'Array.empty[String]'? I find the below answer superior, as it is less ambiguous when read.

Answer (score 68):

```
val emptyArray =  Array.empty[Type]
```

Comment: This worked for me too when the type could be inferred:  Array.empty

Answer (score 6):

`Array()` will be enough, most of the times. It will be of type `Array[Nothing]`.

If you use implicit conversions, you might need to actually write Array[Nothing], due to [Bug #3474](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3474):

```
def list[T](list: List[T]) = "foobar"
implicit def array2list[T](array: Array[T]) = array.toList
```

This will not work:

```
list(Array()) => error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
    found   : [T]Array[T]
    required: List[?]
        list(Array())
                  ^
```

This will:

```
list(Array[Nothing]()) //Nothing ... any other type should work as well.
```

But this is only a weird corner case of implicits. It's is quite possible that this problem will disappear in the future.

Answer (score 6):

If the array type is one of the primitives, you can use the shortcuts from scala.Array.

For example for a byte array it would be:

```
val arr = Array.emptyByteArray
```

This is useful when the type cannot be inferred and you want to remain less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I like the expressiveness of:

```
Array.empty[String]
```