# Initializing Array of list of pair

Tags: scala

I've this class:

```
abstract class SimpleHashTable extends HashTable {
  type Bucket = List[Pair[K, V]]
  type Table = Array[Bucket]

  def alloc_data(size: Int): Table = { 
         var tb = new Table(size)
         //tb.apply(_ =>  Nil)
```

I'm not sure how to initialize the contents of the `Table` to `Nil`?

Please advise. Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Use `var tb = Array.fill(size)(List[Pair[K,V]]())`

```
scala> type Bucket = List[Pair[Int, String]]
defined type alias Bucket

scala> type Table = Array[Bucket]
defined type alias Table

scala> val tb:Table = Array.fill(5)(List[Pair[Int, String]]())
tb: Table = Array(List(), List(), List(), List(), List())
```

Edit:
Actually this syntax might be a bit easier to read :

```
scala> val tb:Table = Array.fill(5)(Nil)
tb: Table = Array(List(), List(), List(), List(), List())
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to initialize it to an empty Array?

```
var tb = Array()
```

**Edit**:

[Canonical way for empty Array in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093973/canonical-way-for-empty-array-in-scala)